# Start a Lync IM conversation for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, lync, skype-for-business

I want to launch Skype for business on chat dialog page but I always launch an app on Contacts tab.

I've tried:

```
"lync:<im:" + email + ">"
```

and

```
"im:<sip:" + email + ">"
```

but above urls don't work as well

Answer (score 0):

This is the Skype [URI Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx#Anchor_3) and according to this, your call should be

```
skype:skype.test.user.1?chat
```